# why does JDK add's an element to UnmodifyableList, if we add element in parent List

Tags: java, collections

```
 List<Person> intList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        // creating Parent List
        // Person Class contains two fields Name and Age
        Person p1 = new Person("James", 28);
        Person p2 = new Person("Duncan", 26);
        Person p3 = new Person("Lukan",32);
        Person p4 = new Person("Therry", 12);
        // Creating ParentList
        intList.add(p1);
        intList.add(p2);        
        intList.add(p3);
        intList.add(p4);

        ImmutableList<Person> immutableList = ImmutableList.copyOf(intList);        
        List<Person> unModifybale = Collections.unmodifiableList(intList);
        //Adding element to parentList
        intList.add(p4);        

        System.out.println("\n" +intList);  

        // Here unModifyble List also gets element after added in parent list
        // why does it happen like this?

        System.out.println("\n unModifyble"+ unModifybale);

        System.out.println("\n Immutable" + immutableList)
```

Comment: What is your issue ?

Answer (score 6):

From [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29):

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.

You've created a *view* into the original list - changes to the original list will be reflected via the view.

Comment: my issue here is as per java docs "Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list." Then  am expecting that UnmodifyableView should not get affected after adding an element to original List as unmoifiable viewList is itself an object, representing a List or CopyOfElements from OriginalList

Comment: @RohitKolhekar - Yes - you cannot modify the list via the view.  If you want something truly immutable, then create an immutable copy (as you're already doing in your example code).

Comment: "view" means you can view the current state of the list, without being able to modify it via this reference to the list. you "view" the data structure, nothing else. manipulating the original instance of the list yourself is sth rather unusual.

Comment: Yes Oliver, I agree to you, we can not modify the the view returned by UnmodifyableList function however, below understanding of mine is what bothering me " as here is as per java docs "Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list." Then am expecting that UnmodifyableView should not get affected after adding an element to original List as unmoifiable viewList is itself an object, representing a List or CopyOfElements from OriginalList"

Comment: @RohitKolhekar You misinterpret the concept of a "view" in its data structural meaning.

Comment: Imagine a flight from 30k feet: you can view the things on planet earth, but you're not able to change anything happening on the ground, you are forced to view what's happening. on earth: things change all the time, so might your elements in the original list. Down on earth you could influence it directly.

Comment: @MWiesner, thanks it helps a lot. One last point. List is itself an Object on Heap. After creating UnModifiableList it returns a List which itself an refrence to OrignalListObject however when we make any add operation on ModifiableList it throw exception. I believe that time JDK checks that OperationObejct is instanceOf ModifiableList.with that say do you think UnmodifiableList contains a List ReferenceVariable(instanceVariable) to OriginalList. just curious to think about it :)

Comment: thanks a lot for help, I am throught with this now :)

Answer (score 1):

adding to @Oliver answer

> From [the
>   Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29):
>
> > Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.
>
> You've created a *view* into the original list - changes to the
>   original list will be reflected via the view.

Basically all update operations like add, remove etc are disabled and overridden to throw UnsupportedOperationException. **It is decorating the list with readonly operations**. An example of **DECORATOR PATTERN**.

```
//all update kind of operations method body
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
```

While creating unmodifiable list, it does not copy the elements of the list. Instead it stores the reference of the list. When you iterate through the unmodifiable list, it returns an iterator to the actual list.

Collections.unmodifiableList internally uses UnmodifiableCollection constructor. You can see in the following extracted code that it stores a reference to the collection.

```
    //reference variable for the list
    final Collection<? extends E> c;

    UnmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        if (c==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.c = c; // storing the reference
    }
```

Therefore, as @Oliver mentioned, unmodifiable list acts like a view meaning you cannot update the list through a view but can only view.

Comment: perfect as I have mentioned in my last comment. I am unable to open the class file in eclipse else i would have hit that Eye :) thanks and cheers

Comment: *"I am unable to open the class file in eclipse ..."* ... I assume that you mean the Java class library source file.  1) That is easy to fix.  2) You can also browse the source code for the Java class libraries online.  For example Google "java.util.List source" ....

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> "Then I am expecting that UnmodifyableView should not get affected after adding an element to original List as unmodifiable viewList is itself an object, representing a List or CopyOfElements from OriginalList".

This seems to be the core of your misunderstanding.

The view list is indeed an Object.  However, it does not represent a snapshot in time of the original list<sup>1</sup>.  Rather, it "represents"<sup>2</sup> the underlying list as it is *right now*.

---

<sup>1 - If that was the intention for this API, they would state it clearly in the javadocs.</sup>

<sup>2 - I'm not sure that the word "represents" is the correct term here.  I would use "represents" for situations where the list data structure is representing something in the physical world, or some higher up in the conceptual space that the application is "modelling".  In this context, the unmodifiable view list conceptually >>is<< the list that it is the view of.  In fact, it could be your incorrect application of the word "represents" that is the root cause of your confusion.</sup>

Comment: Stephen I already thank to Oliver, he explained me well, i am good with this. Thanks anyways